# Maintaining a long-running task on Linux

Tags: linux, process

My system includes a task which opens a network socket, receives pushed data from the network, processes it, and writes it out to disk or pings other machines depending on the messages.  This task is intended to run forever, and the service is designed to have this task always running.  But sometimes it crashes.

What's the best practice for keeping a task like this alive?  Assume it's okay for the task to be dead for up to 30 seconds before we restart it.

Some obvious ideas include having a watchdog process that checks to make sure the process is still running.  Watchdog could be triggered by `cron`.  But how does it know if the process is alive or not?  Write a pidfile?  `touch` a heartbeat file?  An ideal solution wouldn't continuously spin up more processes if the machine gets bogged down to the point where the watchdog is running faster than the heartbeat.

Are there standard linux tools for this?  I can imagine a solution that uses a message queue, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea or not.

Comment: Voting to move to superuser, unix.se would probably be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the nature of the task that you wish to monitor, one method is to write a simple wrapper to start up your task in a fork().

The wrapper task can then do a waitpid() on the child and restart it if it is terminated.

This does depend on modifying the source for the task that you wish to run.

Answer (score 2):

`sysvinit` will restart processes that die, if added to `inittab`.

If you're worried about the process freezing without crashing and ending the process, you can use a heartbeat and hard kill the active instance, letting init restart it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) along with [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/). There are lots of tools for this in the *nix world.

Answer (score 2):

**Supervisor** was designed precisely for this task. From the [project website](http://supervisord.org/):

> Supervisor is a client/server system that allows its users to monitor and control a number of processes on UNIX-like operating systems.

It runs as a daemon (`supervisord`) controlled by a command line tool, `supervisorctl`. The configuration file contains a list of programs it is supposed to monitor, among other settings.

The number of options is quite extensive, -- have a look at the [docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings) for a complete list. In your case, the relevant configuration section might be something like this:

```
[program:my-network-task]
command=/bin/my-network-task   # where your binary lives
autostart=true                 # start when supervisor starts?
autorestart=true               # restart automatically when stopped?
startsecs=10                   # consider start successful after how many secs?
startretries=3                 # try starting how many times?
```

I have used Supervisor myself and it worked really well once everything was set up. It requires Python, which should not be a big deal in most environments but might be.

Comment: I ended up using supervisord.  I found the experience really painful.  Lots of known, long-standing bugs.  It is designed for exactly this, but so are other projects like god or monit.  I wish I had chosen something else.  YMMV.